# Criar nova coluna a partir de coluna existente no R

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr

Tenho um banco de dados em que a primeira coluna possui o código das disciplinas da minha instituição e a segunda coluna possui o nome da respectiva disciplina. Desejo criar uma terceira coluna em que as entradas dependem do código da disciplina. Por exemplo, se a disciplina tem iniciais **AGF** desejo que na coluna criada apareça o curso de **AGRONOMIA**, se as iniciais são **ADF**, quero que na entrada correspondente da coluna criada apareça **ADMINISTRACAO**. Bem como, **MAF** corresponde a **MATEMATICA**, **QMF** corresponde a **QUIMICA** e assim por diante. Segue a planilha que tenho:

```
link <- 
url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/tab.txt")
tab <- read.table("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/tab.txt",sep = "\t",header = TRUE)
```

Como proceder essa construção no R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo faz o desejado.

```
library(dplyr)

tab_mini <- head(tab)

tab_mini %>%
  mutate(Cd_Disciplina_Simples = sub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*", "\\1", Cd_Disciplina)) %>%
  mutate(Curso = recode(Cd_Disciplina_Simples,
                        ADF = "ADMINISTRACAO",
                        AGF = "AGRONOMIA",
                        BQF = "BIOQUIMICA")) %>%
  select(-Cd_Disciplina_Simples)

  Cd_Disciplina             Nome_Disciplina         Curso
1       ADF 401            SOCIOLOGIA RURAL ADMINISTRACAO
2       AGF 100      INTRODUÇÃO À AGRONOMIA     AGRONOMIA
3       AGF 150             DESENHO TÉCNICO     AGRONOMIA
4       BQF 100      BIOQUÍMICA FUNDAMENTAL    BIOQUIMICA
5       BQF 101 LABORATÓRIO DE BIOQUÍMICA I    BIOQUIMICA
6       BQF 102           BIOQUÍMICA BÁSICA    BIOQUIMICA
```

Apliquei ele apenas às seis primeiras linhas do conjunto de dados original porque são muito códigos diferentes. Imagino que o meu exemplo seja suficiente para dar prosseguimento ao que é desejado.

O que meu código faz é o seguinte:

1. Através de uma expressão regular, eu crio uma coluna chamada `Cd_Disciplina_Simples`. Como os códigos das disciplinas são do tipo `ABC XYZ`, apenas a parte `ABC` é necessária para determinar o curso. Assim, a expressão regular que coloquei ali serve justamente para extrair apenas as letras do código da disciplina.
2. A função `recode` é aplicada em `Cd_Disciplina_Simples` justamente para fazer a conversão pedida na pergunta original: `ADF` vira `ADMINISTRACAO`, por exemplo. Como o `R` não sabe o que significa cada um dos códigos de disciplinas com três letras, é necessário entrar com o significado deles manualmente.
3. Como a coluna `Cd_Disciplina_Simples` não é necessária ao final, a função `select` retira ela do conjunto de dados final. Caso ocorra algum conflito entre funções `select` de pacotes diferentes, substitua a linha

   `select(-Cd_Disciplina_Simples)`

por

```
dplyr::select(-Cd_Disciplina_Simples)
```

Assim o `R` será informado que, obrigatoriamente, ele deve usar a função `select` do pacote `dplyr`.

Comment: Obrigado Marcus Nunes, resolveu!!!